# Xamarin.Forms page not displaying xaml layout

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a contentpage in c# along with a xaml file.

Page1.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace CompanyName.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CompanyName.Pages.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   x:Name="test"
                   />
            <Button Text="Hello, World!" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is a fairly large project so to isolate anything that could be causing issues, I set my MainPage to Page1.

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using CompanyName.DataBases;
using CompanyName.Pages;
using CompanyName.Models;

namespace CompanyName
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

   

        public static String OnDatabasesLoaded { get; } = "DatabasesLoaded";

        public static Boolean IsDatabasesLoaded { get; private set; }
       
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

          // The below line is my normal entry point
         //   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2196f3"),BarTextColor=Color.White};

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1()); // I added this to see if Page1 would even work
        }

        

        protected async override void OnStart()
        {

            // Create the tabels

            /*
            ColorDatabase colorDatabase = await ColorDatabase.Instance();
            QuiltDatabase quiltDatabase = await QuiltDatabase.Instance();
            TextDatabase textDatabase = await TextDatabase.Instance();
            */

           


        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }


   
}
```

My problem is that my xaml file is not rendered. On both a physical device and the emulator, a blank screen appears (excluding the navigation bar at the top). Both the xaml and code behind are set as Embedded Resources. I am using Visual Studio 2022 with Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2478. I made a new project and I was able to create a new page and the layout displayed fine.

I haven't been able to see if this error happens on ios. All my testing has been on Android.

Thanks

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in the Page1 constructor is it hit?  Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution?

Comment: @Jason I have cleaned and rebuilt many times. I placed a breakpoint in the constructor and it was never hit.

Comment: do you have more than one class named Page1?  Put a breakpoint in the App constructor and step through the code to where it is getting stuck

Comment: @Jason None of the breakpoints are hitting on Page1. I'm wondering if something internal is pointing to a different class

Answer (score 0):

*"Both the xaml and code behind are set as Embedded Resources."*
Why? code and xaml are not resource types. VS has to "compile" those files.

Let VS correctly insert them into your project:

- Copy those files someplace safe outside the project.
- Delete them from project.
- Rt-click on project / Add New Item / Content Page, name "Page1".
- Then open your originals in a text editor, so you can copy the text, paste them into the files created by VS.

Comment: I was curious about this too, but EmbeddedResource seems to be the default for XAML files

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't looked at csproj for that in a long time. Perhaps the pre-compile is partially at run-time. Or maybe xaml started out as regular resources, and devs left that as the build action for backward compatibility. Regardless, we know VS needs a compile dependency, so best to let it put what is needed in csproj.